# Create a file and write data into it with ionic

Tags: jquery, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm developping an application for mapping purpose..
I created KML and JSON string and I need to store them in files in phones memory, to do so, I used the following code:

```
 var fileObject;

  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);

  function onDeviceReady() 
  {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,onFileSystemSuccess, fail);
  }

  function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt",{create: true, exclusive: false},gotFileEntry, fail);
  }

  function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    fileObject = fileEntry;
    $('#saveFile_btn').on('click', function() {
      saveFileContent();
    });
  }

  function saveFileContent() {
    fileObject.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
  }

  function gotFileWriter(writer) {
    var myText = document.getElementById('my_text').value;
    writer.write(myText);
    writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
      $('#message').html('<p>File contents have been written.<br /><strong>File path:</strong> ' + fileObject.fullPath + '</p>');
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsText(fileObject);
      reader.onload = function(evt) {
        $('#contents').html('<strong>File contents:</strong> <br />'+ evt.target.result);
      };
    };
  }

  function fail(error){
    alert(error.code);
  }
```

the result was not an error, but I can't find the file in the memory.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0L2im.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bingo
Only root access can see those files. It's to keep apps safe from being broken by people who delete stuff at random.

I used `Root Explorer` to access the files from the android device, and `adb pull` to copy them to computer.